# ubuntu boot confirmation

Tags: boot, grub2, startup

i wanna know is it possible to disable ubuntu for boot selection on start up, because sometime after reset (usually on power loss) it needs to be confirmed, I would like to make ubuntu to boot ALWAYS the default value, without confirmation
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

You need to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file by typing `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

Then reduce the Timeout value to 0. Save and close. Then run `sudo update-grub` in a terminal.